Error when using animated(GIF) images in tkinter window in python language
I have a problem related to the use of tkinter (Python) when using an animated image (GIF file). The thing is that the animated image (GIF file) is not played in my program, but only a couple of pixels are shown and how to make the gif files play continuously (until I close the program).
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Main Window")
root.geometry('300x400')

def open_second_window():
    second_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    second_window.title("menu")
    second_window.geometry('700x700')


    image_path = "menu.png"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


    label = tk.Label(second_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo  
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    label.place(x=0, y=0)



    button = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', wraplength=289, text="First gif", command=open_firtsgif_window)

    button.place(x=308, y=302, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', wraplength=289, text="Second gif", command=open_secondif_window)
    button1.place(x=688, y=302, anchor='ne')

def open_firtsgif_window():
    firtsgif_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    firtsgif_window.title("fitrs_gif")
    firtsgif_window.geometry('700x700')


    image_path = "road-sign-roadtrip.gif"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


    label = tk.Label(firtsgif_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo  
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    label.place(x=0, y=0)

    tk.Label(firtsgif_window, font='Times 30', text="firts gif", fg="red").place(x=150, y=30)

    button = tk.Button(firtsgif_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="Exit", command=Close)

    button.place(x=308, y=302, anchor='ne')


def open_secondif_window():
    secondif_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    secondif_window.title("second_gif")
    secondif_window.geometry('700x700')


    image_path = "road-sign-roadtrip.gif"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


    label = tk.Label(secondif_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo  
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    label.place(x=0, y=0)

    tk.Label(secondif_window, font='Times 30', text="Second gif", fg="red").place(x=150, y=30)

    button = tk.Button(secondif_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31',  text="Exit", command=Close)

    button.place(x=308, y=302, anchor='ne')


def Close(): 
    root.destroy() 


button = tk.Button(root, text="Open Second Window", command=open_second_window)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()

How to make GIF files in the code play automatically.

There is no code about doing animation on the GIF image.  Also it is better to post the error traceback if any when your code is executed.

This question is similar to: Play an Animated GIF in python with tkinter. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
